# how to freeze and unfreeze the game loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, pass-by-reference, sdl-2, game-loop

i have a game loop, i want to be able to make it temporary stop and then make it run again.

**I TRIED** to freeze and unfreeze the game by passing a boolean variable by reference to void functions, which their job is to set the variables value to true and false.

there are 3 functions in the game loop here is a pseudo code:

```
while(!quit)  
     if(!freeze):  
     [handle events()] -> [move()] ->[render()] (REPEAT)
```

```cpp
void game_over(int *flag);
void restart_game(int *flag);

void game_over(int *flag)`  
{  
    *flag = 0;  
}  
void restart_game(int *flag)  
{  
    *flag = 1;  
}

int main()  
{  
    //freeze boolean flag initially false  
    int freeze = 0;  
    SDL_event e;  
    //game loop  
    int quit = 0;  
    while(!quit)  
    {  
        if(!freeze)  
            {  
                 while(SDLPollEvent(&e) != 0)  
                 {  
                      switch(e.key.keysym.sym)  
                      {  
                           case SDLK_t:  
                               game_over(&freeze);//passing freeze address  
                               break;  
                           case SDLK_r:  
                               restart_game(&freeze);  
                               break;  
                      }  
                 }  
                 move();  
                 render();  
            }  
    }  
    close();  
    return();
}
```

**PROBLEM IS** when i press r ( when the restart-game() is called) the program becomes so heavy that i can hardly close it (infinity loop) .
can anyone think of what needs to be fixed or what is perhaps a better approach?

Comment: That code formatting went really wrong. Use four spaces to indent and it all works out.

Comment: @tadman does it look good now?

Comment: Infinitely better. Nice!

Comment: Note: `restart-game` is not a valid function name in C++. You *must* use an underscore for things like that. `-` is not valid syntax.

Comment: When you press R, doesn't `freeze` become 1 and an infinite `while (!quit)` loop runs uncontrolled?

Comment: oh YESS, so i have to keep poll_event if freeze is true, that WORKED thanksss
@tadman

Comment: Also keep `render()` when freezed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat why ?

Comment: From what I understand, sometimes the window contents can get corrupted (e.g. when you minimize/maximize the window). Then you'll get `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED` telling you to redraw, but you might as well redraw every frame for simplicity.

Comment: here is the final project :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAgkgOfxJ0Q&t=5s